# How to use sendBodyAndProperty in camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a processor with below code

```
ProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndProperty("direct:endpoint", body, property, propertyValue)
```

I need to use propertyValue in the below route()

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:endpoint" />
    <to uri="file:/?fileName=${propertyValue}" />
</route>
```

Please advice

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712421/how-to-retrieve-a-exchange-property-in-the-camel-route-xml

Answer (score 0):

With the producer method `sendBodyAndProperty` you are setting an *exchange property* : so you can simply use [Exchange Property](http://camel.apache.org/exchangeproperty.html) EL in your route definition.

Assuming your property key is "targetFileName", you can write:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:endpoint" />
    <to uri="file:/?fileName=${exchangeProperty.targetFileName}" />
</route>
```

Comment: thank you for your help!!!  dynamic uri cannot be framed using <to ....> component. so i tried with recipientlist. like below  recipientList(simple("file:/?fileName=${exchangeProperty.targetFileName}"));

Comment: strange.. I made a test with Java DSL and Camel version 2.22.0, it's working fine:  `to("file:/?fileName=${exchangeProperty.targetFileName}")`. Did it work with recipientlist  ?

Comment: Could not resolve placeholder 'exchangeProperty.signFileName' in string value "file:encrypt/destination?fileName=${exchangeProperty.signFileName}"

Answer (score 0):

After making below change it worked like charm..thank you @M.Ricciuti

```
.to("file:?fileName=$simple{exchangeProperty.targetFileName}")
```